# Wordpress wp_link_pages top and bottom of post

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got wp_link_pages added to the bottom of my posts using this in functions.php:

```
function custom_pagination( $content ) {
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $content .= wp_link_pages('echo=0');
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','custom_pagination', 1 );
```

However this only adds it to the bottom but I'd also like to add them to the top of the post how would I go about achieving this? I'm having to use the function method due to also using jetpack related posts (Which the links appear below it if I don't use this method).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is appending (i.e. `.=`) the `wp_link_pages`. Instead, you could do something like:

```
function custom_pagination( $content ) {
    if( is_singular() ) {
        $content = wp_link_pages('echo=0') . $content . wp_link_pages('echo=0');
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','custom_pagination', 1 );
```